# Claims added in Startup not found in Blazor page

Tags: c#, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-5.0

In order to get group membership functionality in our Blazor app based on Azure B2C, I add some claims in the Server project in Startup.cs. When I inspect the User object in the razor pages, the claims I added are not present.

**Startup.cs, public void Configure():**

```
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.User != null && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var groups = GetGroupsFromAzureB2c(context.User);
                
                // Attempt A, separate Identity
                ClaimsIdentity i = new(context.User.Identity);
                i.AddClaims(groups.Select(g => new Claim("Group", g)));
                context.User.AddIdentity(i);

                // Attempt B: Adding claims to the existing Identity
                ((ClaimsIdentity)context.User.Identity).AddClaims(groups.Select(g => new Claim("Group", g));
            }
            await next();
        });
```

**page.razor, protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync():**

```
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    var user = authState.User;

    if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var _claims = user.Claims;
    }
```

_claims only holds the 12 claims that were added automatically, never the 4 claims I added in Startup.cs.

Are there different instances of the User object? Am I adding the claims incorrectly?

Comment: What flavor of Blazor do you use ?

Comment: @enet web assembly, I updated the tag

Comment: Have you confirmed that context.User is ever not null during configuration in startup?

Comment: Is there anything else in your startup.cs Configure that would be causing this to not be executed?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 it's never null, even the first time the code is called the user is already present

Comment: @cwalvoort nothing I can think of, the middleware added above is pretty basic. Plus I can see the claims getting added correctly.
I have a feeling the User in startup is not the same User object from the razor pages...

Comment: How are you adding the AuthenticationStateProvider? Are you using AddScoped or AddSingleton? AddSingleton would cause this to always use the initial service registered.

Comment: At this point, I'm throwing spaghetti at the wall and hoping something sticks.  Is the user identity during startup the SAME as the one that's hit after configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the comments all, I've added my answer which seems to solve the issue.

Comment: If that's the answer, then mark it as the answer. :D

Comment: "You can accept your own answer in 20 hours"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are two separate Identities at play in a Blazor app. One in the Client code and a separate one in the Server code.

We fixed this by adding a `CustomUserFactory` that inherits from `AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>`. We retrieve the AzureB2C roles from a central method using the Graph API for the client side which we call in Program.cs with

```
    builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("xxx");
    })
        // here we hook up our custom factory
        .AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserFactory>();
```

For the server side code, we use the same central method to get the roles from AzureB2C which we call from Startup.cs with

```
    services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context => {/*add roles here*/}
```